# How to pass FlatList item to modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList with some items. These items are clickable from a TouchableOpacity that brings up a Modal. The Modal is gonna show some more info about the item. How can I pass the FlatList item to the modal?

CODE:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginRight: 20,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 2,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.25,
            shadowRadius: 3.84,
            elevation: 3,
            backgroundColor: colors.card,
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true, item);
          }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.company}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text, fontWeight: '700' }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.gluten}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.id}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

............................................................................

```
<Modal
        animationType="fade"
        hardwareAccelerated={true}
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: colors.Modal,
            margin: 20,
            padding: 35,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 2,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.25,
            shadowRadius: 4,
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: 10,
            height: '85%',
          }}>
          <AntDesign
            name="closecircleo"
            size={20}
            color={colors.text}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
          />
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{}</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

..........................................

```
<FlatList
  data={filteredDataSource}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()} 
  renderItem={renderItem} 
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make author variable like detail item and on TouchableOpacity onpress event put your item in that and you can access in your model and on model onRequestClose empty that veriable like that

```js
const [details,setDetails] = useState(null);

<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
              setDetails(item)
}}>
....
</TouchableOpacity>


<Modal
onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          setDetails(null)
        }}
>
<Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{Details.company}</Text>
</Modal>
```

may this help you

Comment: This method is working. But I had to change useState to (" ") instead of null, otherwise I got an error